# Oracle db query for regex is not giving correct result

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g

I am using Oracle database and table

```
-----------------------------
ID   :  NAME
------------------------------
```

Now I need to know know how many name follow folling condition

1. Can contain A to Z
2. Can contain a to z
3. Can contain _

I have written query

```
SELECT *
FROM REGEX_TEST
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE (name,'[A-Za-z0-9_]')
```

But this is not giving me correct result

Sample result which I want

```
ID  Text          Expected result
1   PLAN_20001    PASS
2   A937AH        PASS
3   556679815     PASS
4   A93_7AH       PASS
5   PLANavd20001  PASS
6   A93*7AH       FAIL
7   A93%7AH       FAIL
8   A93^7AH       FAIL
9   A93$7AH    FAIL
10  A93@7AH       FAIL
11  A93!7AH       FAIL
12  A93~7AH    FAIL
13  A93+7AH       FAIL
```

//------------ RESULT -----------

```
1   PLAN20001
2   A937AH
3   556679815
4   A93 7AH
5   PLANavd20001
6   A93*7AH
7   A93%7AH
8   A93^7AH
9   A93$7AH
10  A93@7AH
11  A93!7AH
12  A93~7AH
13  A93+7AH
```

Comment: Sow sample data, the result you get and the expected result. Also the ddl.

Comment: The aggregate function COUNT is used to count rows.

Comment: You mean can contain A-Z, a-z, 0-9 but no other characters?

Comment: Do you want the FAIL rows to be returned (with FAIL text), or not returned at all?

Comment: @jarlh : (1) Yes I want only A-Z a-z and _ (2) I don't want result with fail text but I want all the result which will pass

Comment: @Jens : I have updated my question as you have suggested can you please look in this once

Comment: You miss the input and the result you got from your query.

Comment: Isn't _ a regexp wildcard, i.e. needs to be escaped?

Comment: You have "0-9" in your regexp pattern.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Yes I want number also to be included... I didn't get what you want to convey?

Comment: @Arvind I think you could use some work on explaining what it is that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment your pattern is matching any character in the name; it will only exclude values that do not contain any of those ranges at all, rather than what you seem to want which is to exclude values that contain anything else. So you need to anchor the pattern with ^ and $, and add a quantifier to allow the pattern to be repeated, with either * or ?. So the pattern becomes `'^[A-Za-z0-9_]*$'`.

Demo with a CTE to represent your sample data:

```
WITH REGEX_TEST (id, name) AS (
  select 1, 'PLAN20001' from dual
  union all select 2,'A937AH' from dual
  union all select 3, '556679815' from dual
  union all select 4, 'A93 7AH' from dual
  union all select 5, 'PLANavd20001' from dual
  union all select 6, 'A93*7AH' from dual
  union all select 7, 'A93%7AH' from dual
  union all select 8, 'A93^7AH' from dual
  union all select 9, 'A93$7AH' from dual
  union all select 10, 'A93@7AH' from dual
  union all select 11, 'A93!7AH' from dual
  union all select 12, 'A93~7AH' from dual
  union all select 13, 'A93+7AH' from dual
)
SELECT *
FROM REGEX_TEST
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (name, '^[A-Za-z0-9_]*$');

        ID NAME       
---------- ------------
         1 PLAN20001   
         2 A937AH      
         3 556679815   
         5 PLANavd20001
```

I've left the numeric range 0-9 in despite you saying twice that you only want letters and underscores, as your reply to David Aldridge then said you did want numbers too.

You could also use the alphanumeric class instead of your ranges, which handles other languages more safely (depending on what you want to match, of course):

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (name, '^[[:alnum:]_]*$');
```

Or the [Perl-influenced](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS235) \w operator:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (name, '^\w*$');
```

Or the not-word operator, which doesn't need to be anchored:

```
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE (name, '\W');
```